# SharePoint 2010 List Populated From Access

Tags: list, ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a List within SharePoint 2010 and would like certain fields to be pre-populated from an Access data source, when a field is populated in the SharePoint List.

For example, I have two fields that can be populated in the list. One is the Country and the other is the City. In the Access database there is a list of data showing Cities available for each Country.

The outcome would be when a user selects the country in the SharePoint list, the SharePoint list draws upon the Access database to return the options available to select for city.

If anyone has any experience in this area or can refer me to a thread that already answers this, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If your talking about conditional drop downs,  then share point cannot do this out of the box.  Look at SPUtilities to achieve this,  however it will work on a list that already exists and not from an access Database.

Alternativly,  look at BDCS to achieve this,  though what your trying to do is highly irregular.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use BCS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx) to populate those two list from Access to SharePoint, and use the follwoing to create cascade dropdown in sharepoint column:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using